# SQL Where Clause with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query say
`SELECT name,number FROM TABLE WHERE number='123'`

What I want is to display multiple records using where clause or any other way so that I can get following data.

**Name  Number**

`ABC     123 
PQR     127 
PQR     130`

I tried using `AND` `&&` `,` in where clause.i.e.
`where number=123,127,130` or `where number=123 AND 127 AND 130`etc. but nothing works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just use an `IN` clause

```
where number in (123, 127, 130)
```

you could also use OR (just for info, I wouldn't use this in that case)

```
where number = 123 or
      number = 127 or
      number = 130
```

Don't forget round braces around the "ors" if you have other conditions in your where clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT name,number FROM TABLE WHERE number IN (123,127,130);
```

OR

```
SELECT name,number FROM TABLE
                   WHERE number = 123
                   OR number = 127
                   OR number = 130;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use where in to get multi record
like this,

```
select * from table name
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('12','23','43','46');
```

Result will be :

```
COLUMN_NAME
12
23
43
46
```