# Update records where one field matches any of multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table `Article` containing 2 columns: `ID_LRU` and `Designation`

I want to change the value of `ID_LRU` to `31` when the value of `Designation` =

```
LA2K2B100DF0000
```

or

`SN`

or

`2K2007809`

How can I update them together in the same request ?

Thank you

Comment: `update tablet set colunm1='value1' where column2 in ('x','y','z');`?

Comment: `update SQL Table ID_LRU = 31 where ID_LRU = ID_LRU`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Where Clause with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423903/sql-where-clause-with-multiple-values)

Comment: or [SQL: Update table where column = Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826456/sql-update-table-where-column-multiple-values), or etc. Asked and answered many times over.

Comment: @MagicSenseixd That is a completely useless query that, were it not syntactically invalid, would destroy the IDs of every other record in the table, if anyone was careless enough not to have them set as keys.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for your quickly answer, please write it again but in answer not in comment to mark it resolve.

Comment: So out of a thread that asks a really basic question which is already answered elsewhere, we get a comment and an answer that recommend queries that would destroy the whole table. What a mess.

Comment: @underscore_d it's what he asked for tho

Comment: @MagicSenseixd It's unbelievable to me that you think your suggestion matches what was asked. They want to change only rows where the `Designation` matches one of the 3 options given. Your query, once the syntax was fixed, would tell the server to update every row in the table, whose ID matches its own ID - which is all of them, since that is a tautology that is always true - and then overwrite the ID to 31 for every one. It doesn't filter on `Designation` at all, so it doesn't update the specific row wanted, _then_ it wrecks all of them. By all means - explain to me how that's what they want.

Comment: @vero *Thank you for your quickly answer, please write it again but in answer not in comment to mark it resolve.*  done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is an simple update with an `IN` in the where clause like:

```
update Article set ID_LRU=31 where Designation in ('LA2K2B100DF0000','SN','2K2007809');?
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to perform an `UPDATE` where all of those strings match the `Designation` column in your table `Article`.

```
UPDATE [Article] SET [Article].ID_LRU = 31 WHERE (([Article].Designation="LA2K2B100DF0000") OR ([Article].Designation="SN ") OR ([Article].Designation="2K2007809"));
```

Comment: This will work, but it is far more concise to use `in ('a', 'b', 'c')`. Anyway, this is a blatant duplicate; it does not need more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this May it help

```
Update Article set ID_LRU = 31 where
Designation in ('LA2K2B100DF0000' ,'SN' , '2K2007809')
```

Comment: This pointlessly abstracts simple SQL logic behind a procedure, and worse, it does it wrong: this will overwrite the IDs of _all_ rows in `Article`, since you do nothing to filter to the given `@ID_LRU` and just update the whole table if the given `@Designation` matches the list of choices. This was already pointed out in response to a comment suggesting the same thing in a similarly broken way.

Comment: So, you should either fix the answer or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE Article SET ID_LRU=31 
WHERE Designation='LA2K2B100DF0000' 
   or Designation='SN' 
   or Designation='2K2007809';
```